# Cottage roof leaks

Tags: roof

In a cottage that is unheated in the winter, snow sits on the eaves trough and when it melts it finds a way to seep into the cottage, run along the rafters and get leak into the living area. [image: edge of roof between eaves trough and metal roof] How can I best stop this seepage?

Comment: well, you're missing a drip edge, for one thing. Have you determined *where* the water is getting in? What is in the lower left corner of the picture?

Comment: In the lower left hand corner of the picture is a 2x4 and the eaves trough is attached to the left of that, to ensure that the eaves trough caught water coming off the roof, otherwise the roof over hung too far.

Answer (score 2):

That 2x4 is probably your problem, if snow and ice build up in the gutter (aka eaves trough) high enough then water will flow into the spot where you can see debris there now.

The best thing you could do, without moving the eaves trough and cutting the roof back, is probably to flash with metal. First, I would cut a piece of wood at an angle to sit on top of that 2x4. Then, get a wide piece of flashing. Tuck it up right under the metal roof, and run it down the vertical section, down the newly installed angled piece, and into the back of the eaves trough. That way any water that gets to that space between the roof and the eaves trough can't get behind the flashing, and will eventually make it's way back down.